# In Window Batch - how do I remove leading spaces from a file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a file, ttt.txt. The content/format is like this:

```
  AAA BBB
  AAA CCC
  _
  CCC DDD
```

1. There are 2 leading spaces on each line;
2. There are some lines with only 1 understore sign>

I need to:

1. remove those empty lines with only 1 understore sign (_);
2. I need to trim leader spaces for each line.

Here is my current script:

```
:: ===== Here to underscore lines
type ttt.txt |  findstr /v "^_"  >Final.txt

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (ttt.txt) do (
    set line=%%A
echo(!line:~1!>>myFinal.txt
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When processing text files, the `FOR` processing will automatically remove leading spaces. So the only thing you really have to do is simply check if the line value is equal to an underscore and, if so, ignore it.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (ttt.txt) DO (
    IF NOT "%%A"=="_" ECHO %%A>>myFinal.txt
)

ENDLOCAL
```

---

Edit:  Per your changed requirements, the following would verify the length is 3 or longer as well.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (ttt.txt) DO (
    SET Line=%%A

    REM Verify it is not an underscore.
    IF NOT "!Line!"=="_" (

        REM Check that the length is 3 chars or longer.
        SET Char=!Line:~2,1!
        IF NOT "!Char!"=="" (

            REM All conditions satisfied.
            ECHO %%A>>myFinal.txt
        )
    )
)

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: On top of that, How do I remove lines, where the line only contains less than 3 characters?

Comment: @PaulZ - I have updated the answer per your "new" requirements. Please make sure to list these upfront so you can get the relevant help.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner, you could simplify that a bit. `IF NOT "!Line:~2,1!"=="" ECHO %%A>>myFinal.txt`   Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Squashman - Yes. I was trying to be more deliberate for educational purposes. Also, I separated out the print line in the event more requirements were added ;)

Comment: Still the codes does not work:

After processing, my file shows as:

_                                  
EPMRAXAZFB                       
EPMAXSN 

I used following codes:
    @ECHO OFF
    SETLOCAL
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (tempGrp1.txt) DO (
       SET Line=%%A
       IF NOT "!Line:~2,1!"=="" ECHO %%A>>tempGrp.txt
    )

ENDLOCAL

I expected the first line "_             " (leading underscore with certain white spaces) be removed but this does not seems to be working.

Comment: @PaulZ - Your code in the comment above is not at all what I posted in my answer.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner had your website bookmarked years ago for some batch file stuff.  I see it is no longer there. Can't recall what you all had up there that I used.

Comment: @Squashman I still have them somewhere. If interested I could send them to you (although SO doesn't have a PM system)...

Comment: @JasonFaulkner I just searched for your name in my .bat library.  Found the Random GUID script you wrote. I think I had it because we were discussing a similar topic on DosTips.com.  I am a moderator over there.

Comment: For me it only works if I use at all positions only one "%" instead of two "%%". %A

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%G IN (ttt.txt) DO ECHO %%G|findstr /R /V /C:"^_$">>final.txt
```

EDIT:
Since you are now requesting the line be at least 3 characters long a line with only an underscore at the beginning becomes a mute point.  So all you would need is this.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%G IN (ttt.txt) DO >>Final.txt (ECHO %%G|FINDSTR /R /C:"^...")
```

Comment: On top of that, How do I remove lines, where the line only contains less than 3 characters?

Comment: @PaulZ, I am sure you do not realize that when you add on additional requirements after the fact that the code will completely change which wasted everyone's time.  Is there any other requirements you would like to add before anyone begins to rewrite all their code?

Comment: For me it only works if I use at all positions only one "%" instead of two "%%". %G

Comment: @Deniz open up a command prompt and type: `FOR /?` to read the help file for the command. You will then understand why you only needed to use one percent symbol versus two.