# win cmd: remove whitespace > not enough storage to process this command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, removing-whitespace

I have a long (several million lines) data sheet in plain txt. Looks like this:

```
cellnumber     x-coordinate     y-coordinate     z-coordinate      temperature 
         1 -6.383637190E-01  2.408539131E-02 -5.244855285E-01  3.081549136E+02 
         2 -6.390314698E-01  2.286404185E-02 -5.245100260E-01  3.081547595E+02 
         3 -6.381718516E-01  2.373264730E-02 -5.236577392E-01  3.081547591E+02 
         4 -6.360489130E-01  2.259869128E-02 -5.245736241E-01  3.081547591E+02 
         5 -6.369081736E-01  2.253472991E-02 -5.236831307E-01  3.081547591E+02 
         6 -6.382256746E-01  2.215057984E-02 -5.237988830E-01  3.081547591E+02 
         7 -6.381900311E-01  2.126700431E-02 -5.245448947E-01  3.081547591E+02 
         8 -6.373924613E-01  2.117809094E-02 -5.238834023E-01  3.081547591E+02
```

I currently only have win command line and need to get rid off the whitespaces ath the beginning (their length is not constant as the cellnumber increases) so that I get

```
cellnumber     x-coordinate     y-coordinate     z-coordinate      temperature 
1 -6.383637190E-01  2.408539131E-02 -5.244855285E-01  3.081549136E+02 
2 -6.390314698E-01  2.286404185E-02 -5.245100260E-01  3.081547595E+02 
3 -6.381718516E-01  2.373264730E-02 -5.236577392E-01  3.081547591E+02 
4 -6.360489130E-01  2.259869128E-02 -5.245736241E-01  3.081547591E+02 
5 -6.369081736E-01  2.253472991E-02 -5.236831307E-01  3.081547591E+02 
6 -6.382256746E-01  2.215057984E-02 -5.237988830E-01  3.081547591E+02 
7 -6.381900311E-01  2.126700431E-02 -5.245448947E-01  3.081547591E+02 
8 -6.373924613E-01  2.117809094E-02 -5.238834023E-01  3.081547591E+02
```

May I ask for a solution? I dont have a clue, am not really experienced with this. Thx!

I guess TrimStart may be my friend.

EDIT: I have put together this:

```
@ECHO OFF

set "victim=testJana.txt"

SETLOCAL

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (%victim%) DO (
    IF NOT "%%A"=="_" ECHO %%A>>%victim%_edited.txt
)

ENDLOCAL

pause
```

it works fine for smaller files but Im getting the message

```
not enough storage to process this command
```

Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Window Batch - how do I remove leading spaces from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262660/in-window-batch-how-do-i-remove-leading-spaces-from-a-file)

Comment: Sure. It is similar, thanks. Should I delete now? Do you have any idea regarding this "not enough storage to process this command" issue? Thanks!

Comment: You can always split the input file into smaller files

Comment: @Jewenile try the powershell way, if better

Comment: Nope, I think the edit is just fine, just edit again to refer to original SO answer so users will know that you used a solution without success. Unfortunately aside from splitting the file I've no idea abount the storage issue. Do you have enough disk space?

Comment: Sure, the drive is huge enough. Splitting is not practical in this case.

Comment: What's the approximate file size?

Comment: @Jewenile did you try the answer?

Comment: No, not really. I didnt feel like finding out how to run powershell, what it is etc. Somebody else solved the issue using matlab. Thanks for your concern!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `powershell`:

**First, Second and Third edit**: To be executed in the directory where `data.txt` file is placed and in the `powershell.exe` shell:

(good point to add `-ReadCount` by @lit in other post)

`Get-Content -ReadCount 500 -Path .\path_to_your_source\data.txt | % {$_ -replace " +", " "} | Set-Content -Path .\path_to_our_output\data_no_additional_spaces.txt`

Why -ReadCount makes sense?  Here it takes 500 lines per run via pipes.

Here is the info from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content?view=powershell-5.1) pages)

> -ReadCount
>
> Specifies how many lines of content are sent through the pipeline at a
>   time. The default value is 1. A value of 0 (zero) sends all of the
>   content at one time.
>
> This parameter does not change the content displayed, but it does
>   affect the time it takes to display the content. As the value of
>   ReadCount increases, the time it takes to return the first line
>   increases, but the total time for the operation decreases. This can
>   make a perceptible difference in very large items.

Reads data, replaces all the spaces and then saves data into data_new.txt

This answer was meant for the `powershell.exe` shell not the `cmd.exe` where you normally run your `*.bat` files.  In powershell you have scripts called `*.ps1`.

If you store this the above command in a `trim_space.ps1` and then launch it as (you need to have the script in the same directory as the data being transformed):

`powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass &'C:\path_to_script\trim_space.ps1'`.  You will see it executed.

**Forth edit**

To address your:

> it works fine for smaller files but Im getting the message not enough
>   storage to process this command
>
> Any idea how to deal with this?

You have to process it by chunks which you are not doing in your batch file right now.  You get just to the point where you exhaust all the thread memory and it naturally fails. You need to have approach which allows you to limit the chunk of lines which are processed at once like `-Readcount`.  In batch file I imagine it would be possible to call one batch file from other which would process only limited part of the file.

Comment: Thanks. But that doesnt do anything. After running the bat-file it just flashes and.. nothing appears in the dir.

Comment: you are probably missing something.  Did you start `powershell.exe` instead of `cmd.exe`?  I have tested it on the sample data and it works.

Comment: No. I only saved that into a bat file and double clicked it... I thought that powershell is invoked automatically...

Comment: I think you should note that the answer was specific in that it is `powershell` code not `bat-file`!

Comment: @Jewenile that will not work.  You have to run `powershell.exe` and within the command prompt run the command within the data.txt directory.  (`powershell.exe` is completely different shell than `cmd.exe`)

Comment: The question was to quote "*win command line*" which `powershell.exe` satisfies too.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell, you can limit how much data is processed at a time in the pipeline.

```
Get-Content -Path .\testJana.txt -ReadCount 1000 |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '^ +', '' } |
    Out-File -FilePath .\testJana_edited.txt -Encoding ASCII
```

If you want to run this from a cmd.exe shell, put the PowerShell code above into a file named sourcelimit.ps1 and use the following in a .bat script file.

```
powershell -NoProfile -File .\sourcelimit.ps1
```